# ¿Cómo hacer consultas en múltiples tablas con Hibernate HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Dado los pojos (Clases) que pongo a continuación, ¿cómo se haría la Query siguiente?

**la Query**

```
    SELECT pagina.NombrePagina, user_rol.User_id FROM user_rol 
    INNER JOIN rol_pagina ON rol_pagina.Rol_id = user_rol.roles_id 
    INNER JOIN pagina ON pagina.id = rol_pagina.listaWeb_id
    WHERE user_rol.User_id = 1 AND pagina.NombrePagina = 'mani.jsp'
```

**Pagina.class**

```
       @Entity
public class Pagina {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)//Para generar números 
  autoincrementados
  private int id;
  private String NombrePagina;


  public Pagina() {
    super();

  }


  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getNombrePagina() {
    return NombrePagina;
  }

 public void setNombrePagina(String nombrePagina) {
    NombrePagina = nombrePagina;
 }





}
```

**User.class**

```
@Entity

public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)//Para generar números autoincrementados
private int id;
private String usuario;
private String pass;
private String mail;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //eager = carga ansiosa
private List<Rol>roles = new ArrayList<>();

public User() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public User(int id, String usuario, String pass, String  mail) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.pass = pass;
    this.mail = mail;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}

public String getMail() {
    return mail;
}

public void setMail(String mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public List<Rol> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Rol> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}




}
```

**Rol.class**

```
  public class Rol {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)//Para generar números autoincrementados
private int id;
private String rol;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) //eager = carga ansiosa
private List<Pagina>listaWeb = new ArrayList<>();


public Rol() {
    super();
this.rol = "user";
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}



public String getRol() {
    return rol;
}



public void setRol(String rol) {
    this.rol = rol;
}


public List<Pagina> getListaWeb() {
    return listaWeb;
}


public void setListaWeb(List<Pagina> listaWeb) {
    this.listaWeb = listaWeb;
}



}
```

El motivo por el que no lo se hacer es que, en la BBDD tengo la tabla pagina,user,rol, user_rol y rol_pagina.
Pero en hibernate usas los pojos para hacer las querys, 
¿cómo accedes a esas 2 ultimas tablas?

**Ejemplo de una consulta mia**
**"Consulta para validar un user al logearse"**

```
  public boolean validation(User u) {

    boolean bOk = true;

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    String queryString = "FROM User WHERE usuario = (:condicion) AND pass =(:condicion2)";

    try {
        Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery(queryString);
        hqlQuery.setParameter("condicion", u.getUsuario());
        hqlQuery.setParameter("condicion2", u.getPass());
        u = (User) hqlQuery.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   //           e.printStackTrace();

        bOk = false;
    }

    return bOk; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir? Es decir, tu consulta busca el ID de usuario y el nombre de la página que cumpla que el ID sea 1 y el nombre de la página sea "mani.jsp"... YA tienes los datos

Comment: pero en hibernate no se pueden hacer consultas nativas, es todo a traves de los pojos. Tengo que convertir esa consulta a hibernate.

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que el resultado de la consulta lo tienes antes de hacer la consulta: `select A, B from <loquesea> where A=x and B=y` dará `x,y`a menos que no existan

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar hql (Hibernate Query Language). Basandome solamente en tu query pude hacer esto:

```
String queryHQL="SELECT new Map(p.nombrePagina, ur.id) FROM User_rol as ur
    INNER JOIN Rol_pagina as rp ON rp.id = ur.id 
    INNER JOIN Pagina as p ON p.id = rp.listaWeb_id
    WHERE ur.User_id =:param1 AND p.nombrePagina =:param2 ";
Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Query consultaHQL = session.createQuery(queryHQL);
consultaHQL.setParameter("param1", 1);
consultaHQL.setParameter("param2","mani.jsp");
ArrayList<Map> respuestaHQL=(ArrayList<Map>) consultaHQL.list();
```

En hql le haces consultas a las clases y es indispensable que a cada clase le pongas alias. Ej. `mi.paquete.User_rol as ur` aunque `hql` puede omitir el paquete `User_rol as ur`.

Cuando llamas a un campo pones el nombre de la variable y esta automaticamente llama al metodo set como en: `p.nombrePagina` o en `ur.user_id`.

Tambien como es este el caso solo regresas pares clave/valor lo cual es idoneo para crear un `Map de java` desde hibernate `new Map(...)`. Al final hibernate lo regresa todo en una lista de mapas **en esta consulta**:

```
ArrayList<Map> respuestaHQL=(ArrayList<Map>) consultaHQL.list();
```

Y respondiendo a los comentarios, si puedes ejecutar `sql nativo` desde Hibernate, pero no se recomienda a menos que el `HQL` o `Criteria` sean muy lentos. Pero debes estar consiente de que si haces esto la multiplataforma (respecto a bases de datos) de hibernate se pierde. Esto se hace llamando a `session.createSQLQuery(SQLnativo);`

Comment: a ver, hay cosas que no estoy entendiendo, para empezar yo solo tengo las clases User, Rol y Pagina.   No tengo ninguna clase llamada User_rol, solo la tabla, al igual que Rol_pagina.  Cuando dices eso de poner alias, me lo puedes explicar un poco mejor? osea donde va lo del alias?

Comment: Me base en tu query, no en tus clases. Y con todo respeto si no sabes que es un alias en SQL menos vas a saber en HQL y entonces no deberias estar usando hibernate. Tu pusiste en tu query `FROM user_rol` eso es de una tabla o vista y su alias sería `FROM user_rol as ur` por decir un ejemplo, porque puedes poner `FROM user_rol as juan_perez` y va a funcionar pero no va a ser practico. Investiga mas Se nota que no has buscado nada en la documentación de hibernate sobre HQLSolo busque hql new map y salio esto https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select

Comment: Creo que me as malentendifo, aprecio tu ayuda y por eso te doy las gracias, simplemente había un par de cosas que no terminaba de entender y ya está, no te enfades por eso hombre. La única duda que tengo es: la tabla User_rol y Rol_pagina, se crearon solas automáticamente al hacer las relaciones en los pojos, entonces, aunque no tenga esas clases,  tu ejemplo de query me va a funcionar igual?

Comment: Es que esa es la gran duda que tengo yo: Si `User_rol` y `Rol_pagina` existen en BD hay que crear sus beans de entidad, para que funcione el HQL. En tu código SQL si están pero en tus beans de entidad no las veo, entonces no se si realmente existen o no. Esa es la razón por la cual solo me base en el query para contestarte. Por otra parte te comento que para este caso en especifico con la configuración que veo, hibernate NO va a crear esas tablas automáticamente.

Comment: si eso es cierto, no las crea automaticamente y no se como.